# XML and Java easy task

Tags: java, xml

I'm new in the Java language, and I have a project to do. I need some help for my task, it's not hard but I really don't get it. I own this XML file

```
<LOCATION_PROPERTIES NAME="STN10">
       <LOCATION ID="10" TYPE="P+D" X="52380" Y="24020" ANGLE="90" PICK_BANK="2" PICK_TABLE="10" PICK_MOD="0" PICK_DRV="N->P" DROP_BANK="2" DROP_TABLE="11" DROP_MOD="0" DROP_DRV="N->P"/>
   <SEGMENT_PROPERTIES>
       <NEXT_LOCATION NAME="X535" BANK="3" TABLE="127" MOD="0" DRV="P->P" INITIAL_SPEED="600" SPEED="504" LENGTH="8052" STOP="CS"/>
   </SEGMENT_PROPERTIES>
</LOCATION_PROPERTIES>

<LOCATION_PROPERTIES NAME="STN11">
      <LOCATION ID="11" TYPE="P+D" X="53280" Y="24020" ANGLE="90" PICK_BANK="2" PICK_TABLE="10" PICK_MOD="0" PICK_DRV="N->P" DROP_BANK="2" DROP_TABLE="11" DROP_MOD="0" DROP_DRV="N->P"/>
   <SEGMENT_PROPERTIES>
      <NEXT_LOCATION NAME="X535" BANK="3" TABLE="58" MOD="0" DRV="P->P" INITIAL_SPEED="600" SPEED="502" LENGTH="7893" STOP="CS"/>
   </SEGMENT_PROPERTIES>
</LOCATION_PROPERTIES>

<LOCATION_PROPERTIES NAME="STN12">
      <LOCATION ID="12" TYPE="P+D" X="54180" Y="24020" ANGLE="90" PICK_BANK="2" PICK_TABLE="10" PICK_MOD="0" PICK_DRV="N->P" DROP_BANK="2" DROP_TABLE="11" DROP_MOD="0" DROP_DRV="N->P"/>
   <SEGMENT_PROPERTIES>
      <NEXT_LOCATION NAME="X534" BANK="3" TABLE="59" MOD="0" DRV="P->P" INITIAL_SPEED="600" SPEED="600" LENGTH="4267" STOP="CS"/>
   </SEGMENT_PROPERTIES>
 </LOCATION_PROPERTIES>

 <LOCATION_PROPERTIES NAME="X535">
    <LOCATION ID="535" TYPE="MOVE" X="54090" Y="33800" ANGLE="90"/>
  <SEGMENT_PROPERTIES>
    <NEXT_LOCATION NAME="X536" BANK="1" TABLE="88" MOD="0" DRV="P->P" INITIAL_SPEED="1200" SPEED="1200" LENGTH="3013" STOP="CS"/>
    <NEXT_LOCATION NAME="STN19" BANK="2" TABLE="65" MOD="0" DRV="P->N" INITIAL_SPEED="1043" SPEED="468" LENGTH="5438" STOP="CS"/>
    <NEXT_LOCATION NAME="STN20" BANK="2" TABLE="66" MOD="0" DRV="P->N" INITIAL_SPEED="1200" SPEED="513" LENGTH="6338" STOP="CS"/>
    <NEXT_LOCATION NAME="STN22" BANK="2" TABLE="198" MOD="0" DRV="P->N" INITIAL_SPEED="1200" SPEED="587" LENGTH="8138" STOP="CS"/>
    <NEXT_LOCATION NAME="STN21" BANK="2" TABLE="67" MOD="0" DRV="P->N" INITIAL_SPEED="1200" SPEED="552" LENGTH="7238" STOP="CS"/>
   </SEGMENT_PROPERTIES>
 </LOCATION_PROPERTIES>
```

I succeeded in showing all the stations and the time to all the next locations. It gives me that :

Departure Station : STN10.
Arrival : X535  ---  Time to go : 16 seconds

Departure Station : STN11
Arrival : X535  ---  Time to go : 16 seconds

... // and so on, a whole lot

Departure Station : X535
Arrival : X536  ---  Time to go : 2 seconds
Arrival : STN19 ---  Time to go : 12 seconds
Arrival : STN20 ---  Time to fo : 12 seconds
... // etc

What I need to do is to show the time from one station to an other. Kind of this way :

Departure Station : STN10
Arrival : X535  ---  Time to go : 16 seconds
Arrival : X536  ---  Time to go : 2 seconds
Arrival : X537  --- ...
Arrival : STN26 ---  Total time : ...
... // etc

But now I'm a bit trapped, I think that I have to do it in a recursive way, but I don't know how to proceed.

For now, that is my java code, but I need to create more functions I think.

```
public static int onestep4all()
{
    //int cpt = 0;
    int timeonestep = 0;
    List <Element> location_properties = root.getChildren("LOCATION_PROPERTIES");
    for (Element loc :  location_properties)
    {
        if(loc.getAttributeValue("NAME").startsWith("STN")== true)
        {
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("            Departure Station : "+loc.getAttributeValue("NAME"));
            List <Element> segment_properties = loc.getChildren("SEGMENT_PROPERTIES");
            for (Element seg : segment_properties)
            {
                List <Element> next_location = seg.getChildren("NEXT_LOCATION");
                for (Element next: next_location)
                {
                    System.out.print("Arrival : " +next.getAttributeValue("NAME"));
                    int L = Integer.parseInt(next.getAttributeValue("LENGTH"));
                    int S = Integer.parseInt(next.getAttributeValue("SPEED"));
                    timeonestep = L/S;
                    System.out.println("  ---  Time to go : "+timeonestep+" seconds");                                
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return timeonestep;
}
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: put all the code an xml in a public repo and provide the link please. I can't run this code on my machine.

Comment: Here is my XML File : [URL=http://uptobox.com/vjephjz7ywgw]routes.xml - 85 KB[/URL]

But for the code, I only have different tests on my computer.

Comment: @Lexandro
If you want to read it, use this as a main : 

`
public class JDOM2
{  
    private static final String xmlroutes = "C://Users//Thomas//Desktop//Chalmers//routes.xml";
    
    static Element root;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JDOMException, IOException
    {
        
        SAXBuilder jdomBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document jdomDocument = jdomBuilder.build(xmlroutes);
                                                              
        root = jdomDocument.getRootElement();

        onestep4all()
}
`

Comment: I couldn't download the XML pls send it to lexandro2000 at gmail dot com. Otherwise finally I made the code to run :) So I can investigate it on weekend.

Comment: I put together something and pushed to GitHub: https://github.com/lexandro/stackexchange/tree/master/XML_and_Java_easy_task

I'm not sure what is really you want, but this code creates a list of stations if you specify the first one. It has infinite loop detection and displays only the length/time, but I think this is a usable starting point. If you have questions or request just pls let me know :)